# clutter plugin using npapi

Tags: javascript, webkit, npapi, browser-plugin, clutter

I have developed a plugin using NPAPI for calling Clutter Apis.

I used [OpenGL+Plugin](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/OpenGL+Plugin) as reference while creating the plugin.

Standalone Native Clutter examples run with out any issue.

***My Questions***

1. How can I create a Clutter Stage from the Plugin's *WindowObject*  ?
2. Also, I have read about the Clutter port of Webkit but do not know if it might be helpful for my purpose in any way ?

My platform and version info is:
OS: Win-7
Clutter: 1.10

**EDIT1** :
I am using

```
ClutterStage *stage = clutter_win32_get_stage_from_window(plugin_hwnd);
```

but the plugin times out. Do i need to set anything else for this to work ?

Comment: You mean the plugin is killed by the browser for taking too long? Have you tried attaching a debugger and checking where your plugin hangs?

Comment: Yes. plugins hangs on clutter_main().. Havent tried a debugger yet.

Comment: I don't know Clutter, but `clutter_main()` start it's main loop. I.e. it doesn't return and instead runs a loop which processes events etc., which is something that plugins can't do (the browser is waiting for the plugin functions to return on the main thread). Either there is a way to run clutter on another thread or you find some way to periodically tell clutter to process events.

Comment: I'll try launching clutter_main() in a different thread.

Comment: I launched clutter_main (along with clutter_init) in a different thread, but still nothing is displayed in the browser window. Plugin no longer hangs now.

Comment: Now, when i launch the plugin based app, it opens one new window and displaying the content on that window.I am using clutter_stage_get_default ();  My problem is to display the content on the same window in which it is launched.